# Moment() is not defined in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a working Angular project, and I have been given the work to carry forward the work. 
Since this is a small yet confusing problem for me, after a lot of research I have failed myself to get to the result.

In my project, we have used the moment in the **app.component.ts**, and used the code. The code is below

**1. app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
declare var moment: any;

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

 year = moment().format("YYYY")

 constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

**2. app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<hr>

<section class='container footer'>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <p>Hello {{year}}</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Error comes in this line : `year = moment().format("YYYY")`

As soon as I comment the line, it works, but it is not working when the code includes this.

The error is this :

```
ERROR ReferenceError: moment is not defined
at new AppComponent (app.component.ts:12)
at createClass (core.es5.js:10925)
at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10756)
at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:12197)
at createRootView (core.es5.js:12092)
at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13475)
at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12792)
at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create (core.es5.js:9864)
at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.es5.js:3333)
at ApplicationRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (core.es5.js:4768)
```

After the research, I have tried some more thing, and in my knowledge the thing is not working because the moment is getting loaded before the window loads.

But couldn't find any possible way to rectify it. To your surprise it is working fine on our web, but when I run on my local box it is giving out the same error.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To use any package, you need to install its module through "npm" command and then import it into your module,

Comment: I was doing the same, just the declaration issue. Thanks

Comment: declare var moment: any; this should be declared either inside class constructor or inside ngInit() life cycle hook. Declaring as global wont work, that's why you are getting the error. This has to do with Angular life cycle and scope.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

install moment `npm install moment --save`

use `import * as moment from 'moment';`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

 year = moment().format("YYYY")

 constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Krihsna, it worked. But I don't know why this code didn't work `declare var moment: any;`, as this is the standard declaration of moment in typescript? Thanks

Comment: You declared the variable moment.but that moment has no definition 
ie its not linked with your node module package of moment.so only its not working

Answer (score 2):

Just install it with npm, in your console type

```
npm install --save moment
```

And then in your Angular app, import is as easy as this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

That's it, you get full Typescript support!

```
year = moment().format("YYYY")
```